# How to search array keys with variable part of name?

Tags: php

I have two arrays:

```
$arr1 = [
    'g_0_q_2345' => [
        'aaa' => 'bbb'    
    ],
    'g_0_q_5555' => [
        'ccc' => 'ddd'
    ],
    'g_0_qc_2222' => [
        'eee' => 'fff'
    ]
];
$arr2 = [
    'g_0_q_2345' => 1111,
    'g_1_q_2345' => 2222,
    'g_0_q_5555' => 3333
];
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {

}
```

I have to use array key from $arr1 to search values in $arr2. Array key from $arr2 has a variable part (`g_0_*, g_1_*, g_2_*, ...`) which I don't have in $arr1 (only `g_0_*`). For example, for key `g_0_q_2345` I want to search values `1111` and `2222`. What is the easiest and most optimal way to search values in $arr2?

Comment: do you want to take the first part `g_0_` of the key from `$arr2` and second part `q_2345` from the `$arr1` and get the values from `$arr2` ?

Comment: @OmarAbbas, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try [this](https://tehplayground.com/RxbPE7R7w0ZQFM88), and let me know if it works for you.

```
$arr1 = [
    'g_0_q_2345' => [
        'aaa' => 'bbb'    
    ],
    'g_0_q_5555' => [
        'ccc' => 'ddd'
    ],
    'g_0_qc_2222' => [
        'eee' => 'fff'
    ]
];
$arr2 = [
    'g_0_q_2345' => 1111,
    'g_1_q_2345' => 2222,
    'g_0_q_5555' => 3333
];


$keys1 = array_keys($arr1);
$keys2 = array_keys($arr2);

$search_keys = array_unique(array_merge($keys1,$keys2));

$result = [];
foreach($arr2 as $key=>$val){
    if(in_array($key, $search_keys)){
        $result[] = $val;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```